# How do you request and release audio focus in Here Maps SDK Android

Tags: java, android, audio, here-api

I see in the Here Maps Documentation they provide a very small example of how to request audio focus for voice navigation. 
https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/audio-management.html.

However how should this work? Should we just always request and hold onto "AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK". Is there a way to get callbacks into when Audio is about to start and then request and release?

Also how would we handle if we get a phone call, and we want to pause the navigation voice?

Answer (score 0):

NavigationManager has a [AudioFeedbackListener](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/content/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/guidance/NavigationManager.html#addAudioFeedbackListener-java.lang.ref.WeakReference), you should be able to get callbacks by implementing the listener : onAudioStart() , onAudioEnd().

-